# SQL query to get 3 Months of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve data for 3 months for eg.

I have data in a datetime column.

```
Date_Column
11/22/2012
12/22/2012
01/22/2013
```

I need the above output when I pass the date 12/22/2012.

I am using this but not getting result.

```
where
MONTH(Date_Column) BETWEEN MONTH(DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,'12/22/2012')-1,0))
                AND MONTH(DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,'12/22/2012')+1,0))
                AND YEAR(Date_Column)=YEAR('12/22/2012') 

Group By Month(Date_Column), YEAR(Date_Column)..
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `select * from table where datediff(mm,cast(Date_column) as date),cast(getdate() as date))=3`

Comment: Date_Column is already Datetime and If I am not wrong when we use DATEDIFF fn we dont have to bother about casting of date!!!

Comment: when you pass that date, do you need dates 2012-11-01 until but excluding 2013-02-01 ? Or just the same day

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: When I pass 12 Month I need data for 11,12 and 1(Next year) Months....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all data from the month before, the current month and next month

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2012-12-22'

SELECT
  * 
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE 
  Date_Column >= DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,@date)-1,0) AND
  Date_Column < DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,@date)+2,0)
```

As documentation

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2012-12-22'

SELECT 
  DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,@date)-1,0) [From],
  DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,@date)+2,0) [To]
```

Returns:

```
From        To
2012-11-01  2013-02-01
```

Comment: I used kind of this only:

SET @StartDate=(SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,-2,@Date)), 0))
 SET @EndDate=(SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Date)+1,0)))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write as below :

```
where
MONTH(Date_Column) BETWEEN MONTH(DATEADD(M,-1,'12/22/2012'))
                AND MONTH(DATEADD(M,+1,'12/22/2012'))
```

or

```
where
    Date_Column BETWEEN DATEADD(M,-1,'12/22/2012')
                    AND DATEADD(M,+1,'12/22/2012')
```

Comment: This is the same I am using Just using DateDIFF function to get the more accurate result...

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Declare @CurDate datetime
Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime
Select @CurDate = GETDATE() --Pass Your Date As parameter
Select  @EndDate=DateAdd(M,+1,@CurDate)
Select  @StartDate= DateAdd(M,-1,@CurDate)
Select @CurDate
Select @EndDate
Select @StartDate
WHERE (MONTH(@StartDate) BETWEEN MONTH(@EndDate) AND MONTH(@StartDate))
AND (YEAR(@StartDate) BETWEEN YEAR(@EndDate) AND YEAR(@StartDate))
```

Comment: not working because in BETWEEN we have to give conditions in asc order. I case of January it fails...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

THis is actually based on ACCESS but if you'll be able to convert this in sql , I believe this will work

```
WHERE (((DateDiff("m",Date_Column,'12/22/2012'))=1)) or
 (((DateDiff("m",Date_Column,'12/22/2012'))=0)) or (((DateDiff("m",Date_Column,'12/22/2012'))=-1))
```

I think this is how it must be written in SQL:

```
WHERE Date_Column = DATEDIFF(M, 1 , '12/22/2012') OR
      Date_Column = DATEDIFF(M, 0 , '12/22/2012') OR
      Date_Column = DATEDIFF(M, -1 , '12/22/2012')
```

.

Comment: no its not working...Its taking by default 9
Select DATEDIFF(M, 1 , '12/22/2012') Output--> some garbage value
Select MONTH(DATEDIFF(M, 1 , '12/22/2012')) Output--> 9